# Can't Access Firebase Storage Default Bucket From iOS App

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

A few hours ago I was able to access my default storage bucket without any problems. However, now I can't. I receive the following message:

```
Error Domain=FIRStorageErrorDomain Code=-13021 "User does not have permission to access gs://MY_BUCKET_NAME/data.json." UserInfo={object=data.json, ResponseBody={
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
  }
```

Here's my bucket rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
    match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
            allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
    }
 }
```

I don't know what to do. Can someone help?

Note: I'm on the Blaze plan. firebase-storage@system.gserviceaccount.com is added to my default Firebase Storage bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your rules require that a user be signed into your app in order to read or write any file in the bucket.  I would expect that the only reason why you would get that message is if there was no user signed in, or somehow you are trying to access a bucket that is not in the same project as the signed in user.

Comment: You are correct. For some reason I thought I didn't have to authenticate my requests to default storage bucket because it's configured using the default Firebase app. I guess during development process I logged into a user account (which was created using the Auth library) and that enabled me to access my default storage bucket based on those security rules. I deleted the app but it seems like there was some caching for that authenticated user. Because I was able to access my bucket even though I thought deleting the app also logged me out from the app. Thanks for your answer & videos!!!